# Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

When following the flutter tutorial examples for adding firebase dependancies in the yaml file I would get this printout in the console "Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT":

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.0+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
  firebase_database: ^3.0.3
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.2
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581702/after-admin-logged-in-to-create-user-authentication-email-and-password-fireba

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my particular workflow, when adding firebase dependencies, the tutorial code and flutter warnings never prompted to modify the AppDelegate.m file. It wasn't until I dialed back and added cloud_firestore did I get prompted with this warning:

> 6.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure]; (FirebaseApp.configure() in Swift) to your application initialization.

Read more: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app].

1. open xc workspace >> open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
2. open AppDelegate.m
3. in AppDelegate.m add the following line:

> import Firebase;

4. in AppDelegate.m add the following snippet to your application did finish method

> [FIRApp configure];

Here is what mine looked like in the end:

[image]

Comment: If you would have posted code instead of image that would me much helpful.

Comment: steps 3 and 4 have the code you need "import Firebase;" and "[FIRApp configure];", the image is for context.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:
https://medium.com/vector-com-mm/how-to-fix-ios-crash-during-the-start-firebase-configure-f3477df3154

In AppDelegate.swift change the order of

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

to:

```
FirebaseApp.configure() 
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

clean and rebuild...

My AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Remember to import Firebase, I forgot.. Wonder why this is not mentioned, or not done by flutter build